# Incorrect output in Find number of pairs in array code

Tags: arrays

The question is the find number of pairs in a given array. I am not able to figure out why I am getting incorrect output. Thanks in advance...

Sample Input:
10
1 1 3 1 2 1 3 3 3 3

Expected Output:
4

My output:
2

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sockMerchant(int arr[],int n){
    int arr1[n],pairs=0,k=0;
    bool exist=false;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(arr1[j]==arr[i]){
                exist = true;
            }
        }

        if(!exist){
            int c=0;
            int x = arr[i];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(arr[i]==x){
                    c++;
                }
            }
            arr1[k] = x;
            k++;
            pairs = pairs + c/2;
            exist = false;
        }

    }
    cout << pairs;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    sockMerchant(arr,n);

}
```